# line break in string in c#

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm loading a text from the resource loader which includes '\n' to indicate a new line. A textblock takes this text and displays it, but I can't see the line break? I'm also trying to replace every '\n' by Environment.NewLine, but nothing happens. What can I do?

Here is a little bit code:

```
        TextBlock text = new TextBlock();
        text.FontSize = 18;

        var str = loader.GetString("AboutText");
        //str.Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine);

        text.Text = str;
        text.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Justify;
        text.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
        text.Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 10, 10);
```

Comment: Does it have "\r\n" or just "\n"?

Comment: Have a look of this [question][1]. I think it is the answer.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837367/wpf-textblock-linebreak-in-text-attribute

Comment: Trying \r\n, but nothing happens.

Comment: Adding some code to the question.

Comment: Why can't you use a TextBox with Mode = "Muliline" instead of a TextBlock?

Comment: Because under Windows 8 a TextBox hasn't the property mode wich I can set to multiline.

Comment: have you tried with a hardcoded string like this: var str = "sdfasfasd \n asdasdasd";

Comment: Yes, with the hardcoded string it is working, but I want to use the ResourceLoader for different languages...

Comment: have you checked if the string in ResourceLoader actually contains \n, try running it in debug mode and check the str value

Comment: Yes. The str variable contains \n and it is displayed by the text block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the Resource file is escaping `\n` to `\\n`, this means that there are basically 2 solutions to solve this.

you can either

```
var str = Regex.Unescape(loader.GetString("AboutText"));
```

or in your resx file you can replace \n with normal break line by pressing Shift Enter.

Comment: Yeah! It's working with Regex.Unescape(). Thank you very much!

Comment: Good find. this is an detail easy to overlook. +1

Answer (score 1):

Try "\r\n". It works for me.

```
    TextBlock text = new TextBlock();
    text.FontSize = 18;

    var str = "Hello\r\nWorld";

    text.Text = str;
    text.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Justify;
    text.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
    text.Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 10, 10);
    layoutRoot.Children.Add(text);
```

Comment: Yes, with hardcoded string simply \n is working fine, but if you are using the resource loader it doesn't work...